# Are the "games" and "roleplaying" tags redundant?

Tags: discussion, tags

Given the nature of this site?

Answer (score 11):

"Roleplaying" could be a useful tag to mark questions about the "acting in character" part of gaming, as in the distinction roleplaying vs. combat.  There might be a better tag for that, though.

Comment: Agreed on the "Roleplaying" tag still being relevant. "Games" can probably be re-tagged as "Systems", though.

Comment: Perhaps we should encourage something more like ["method-roleplaying"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_actor) ?

Comment: Yeah, I like "roleplaying" for "acting in character."  It's not quite "acting" (which is externalized), and the term immersion is less widely understood.

Answer (score 1):

I should think so, yes. It seems to me that a site entirely about roleplaying games wouldn't need either tag. :) Retag at will.

Answer (score 0):

"Games" has no purpose and should go.  (or "rpg").  Everything here should fit that tag.

Comment: Well, if it's a question to differentiate between different games, a "games" tag isn't necessarily bad. Renaming it something like "systems", however, would clarify it a lot more.